# MATLAB code to C++ (with OPENCV)

Tags: matlab, histogram

Could someone help me in translating this command into C++ (OpenCV)?

```
[h t] = hist(img(roi_mask>0),2048);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the histogramm you could use the following class (class is from the openCV 2 Computer Vision book):

```
class Histogram1D{
private:
    int histSize[1];
    float hranges[2];
    const float* ranges[1];
    int channels[1];
    cv::MatND hist;
public:
    Histogram1D()
        {
        histSize[0] = 2048;
        hranges[0]=0.0;
        hranges[1] = 255.0;
        ranges[0] = hranges;
        channels[0] = 0;//by default, we look at channel 0
        }
    Histogram1D(float minval,float maxval)
        {
        histSize[0] = 2048;
        hranges[0]=minval;
        hranges[1] = maxval;
        ranges[0] = hranges;
        channels[0] = 0;//by default, we look at channel 0
        }

    //Hier wird die cv funktion zum bestimmen vom Histogramm gestartet
    cv::MatND calcHistogram(const cv::Mat &image){
        //compute histogram
        cv::calcHist(&image,
            1,         //histogram from 1 image only
            channels,  //the channel used
            cv::Mat(), //no mask is used
            hist,      //the resulting histogram
            1,         //it is a 1D histogram
            histSize,  //number of bins
            ranges     //pixel value range
            );
        return hist;
        }

    cv::MatND getHistogram(){


        return hist;
        }

    cv::Mat getHistogramImage(){
        //compute histogram first
        cv::MatND hist= getHistogram();

        //get min and max bin values
        double maxVal=0;
        double minVal=0;
        cv::minMaxLoc(hist, &minVal, &maxVal, 0,0);

        //Image on which to display histogram
        cv::Mat histImg(histSize[0]+40, histSize[0],CV_8U,cv::Scalar(255));

        //set highest point at 90% of nbins
        int hpt = static_cast<int>(0.9*histSize[0]);

        //Draw a vertical line for each bin
        for (int h=0;h<histSize[0];h++)
            {
            float binVal=hist.at<float>(h);
            int intensity = static_cast<int>(binVal*hpt/maxVal);

            //This function draws a line between 2 points
            cv::line(histImg,cv::Point(h,histSize[0]),cv::Point(h,histSize[0]-intensity),cv::Scalar::all(0));
            }

        //min und max val im Histogramm angeben
        char maxValStr[10],minValStr[10];
        sprintf (maxValStr, "%d",static_cast<int>(hranges[1]));
        sprintf (minValStr, "%d",static_cast<int>(hranges[0]));

        int fontFace = cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX;
        double fontScale = 0.3;
        int thickness = 1;  
        cv::Point textOrgmax(histSize[0]-40, histSize[0]+20),textOrgmin(5, histSize[0]+20);

        cv::putText(histImg, maxValStr, textOrgmax, fontFace, fontScale, cv::Scalar::all(0), thickness,8);
        cv::putText(histImg, minValStr, textOrgmin, fontFace, fontScale, cv::Scalar::all(0), thickness,8);
        return histImg;
        }

    };
```

And here is how you could use it:

```
// Transform it into the C++ cv::Mat format
cv::Mat image(imagesource);

// Setup a rectangle to define your region of interest
cv::Rect myROI(10, 10, 100, 100);

// Crop the full image to that image contained by the rectangle myROI
// Note that this doesn't copy the data
cv::Mat croppedImage = image(myROI);


    cv::Mat tmp = croppedImage .clone();//clone image
        double min =0,max = 0;
    cv::minMaxLoc(tmp,&min,&max);

    cv::namedWindow("Histogram",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    Histogram1D h(min,max);
    h.calcHistogram(tmp);
    cv::imshow("Histogram",h.getHistogramImage());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the problem is that the ROI is not a rectangle but something like a circle (but it is not). Furthermore, I used calcHistogram but my source image has some negatives value. I tried to correct it putting the range between 0-255 but it doesn't work well. Is it possible calculate an histogram of an image with negatives values, by using 2048 bins relatives to 256 gray levels?

Comment: You could generate a 1D Image to put the pixel values of the circle image in that 1D image (or better sayd 1D cv::Mat array). In my function you have        hranges[0]=minval;
        hranges[1] = maxval; did you try to use this maybe it will work also for negative values. Try to use the class I posted you I think calcHistogramm is the older C-Style function.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need a histogram of 2048 bins on a masked image returning a matrix holding both counts and the bin values.

I guess you can use calcHist, or even customize it or build your very own function.
You need to know how to access array elements, operations on arrays and basic theory on histograms.

Your question hides many questions because Matlab is of higher level. Break down your problem and you'll find all the answers scattered inside the forum...

Comment: I found this: cvCalcHist( &img, hist, 0, roi_mask); but my problem, now, is to calculate the histgram of an image with negative values

Comment: @user1783116 Use IPL_DEPTH_8S when creating images. S=signed U=unsigned.